# Anagram Solver, array[26] not working correctly

Tags: c, anagram

I've nearly finished my anagram solver program where I input two strings and get the result of whether they are anagrams of each other. For this example i'm using 'Payment received' and 'Every cent paid me'.

The problem i'm getting is when I output the letterCount arrays, letterCount1 is incorrect (it doesn't think there is a character 'd' but there is.) but letterCount2 is correct.

Can anyone see a problem with this because i'm completely baffled?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int checkAnagram(char string1[], char string2[])
{
        int i;
    int count = 0, count2 = 0;
    int letterCount1[26] = {0};
    int letterCount2[26] = {0};

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(string1); i++)
    {
        if(!isspace(string1[i]))
        {
            string1[i] = tolower(string1[i]);
            count++;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(string2); i++)
    {
        if(!isspace(string2[i]))
        {
            string2[i] = tolower(string2[i]);
            count2++;
        }
    }

    if(count == count2)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if(string1[i] >='a' && string1[i] <= 'z')
            {
                letterCount1[string1[i] - 'a'] ++;
            }

            if(string2[i] >='a' && string2[i] <= 'z')
            {
                letterCount2[string2[i] - 'a'] ++;
            }
        }

        printf("%s\n", string1);

        for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", letterCount1[i]);
            printf("%d ", letterCount2[i]);
        }
    }
}

main()
{
    char string1[100];
    char string2[100];

    gets(string1);
    gets(string2);

    if(checkAnagram(string1, string2) == 1)
    {
        printf("%s", "Yes");
    } else
    {
        printf("%s", "No");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are count and count2 giving correct answers?

Comment: You don't return anything from `checkAnagram`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int checkAnagram(char string1[], char string2[])
{
    int i;
    int count = 0, count2 = 0;
    int letterCount1[26] = {0};
    int letterCount2[26] = {0};
    int len1 = strlen(string1);
    int len2 = strlen(string2);

    for(i = 0; i < len1; i++)
    {
        if(!isspace(string1[i]))
        {
            string1[i] = tolower(string1[i]);
            count++;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < len2; i++)
    {
        if(!isspace(string2[i]))
        {
            string2[i] = tolower(string2[i]);
            count2++;
        }
    }

    if(count == count2)
    {
        for (i=0; i<len1; i++)
            if (!isspace(string1[i]))
                letterCount1[string1[i]-'a']++;
        for (i=0; i<len2; i++)
            if (!isspace(string2[i]))
                letterCount2[string2[i]-'a']++;

        int flag = 1;
        for(i = 0; flag && i < 26; i++)
            if (letterCount1[i] != letterCount2[i])
                flag = 0;
        return flag;
    }
    return 0;
}

main()
{
    char string1[100];
    char string2[100];

    gets(string1);
    gets(string2);

    if(checkAnagram(string1, string2) == 1)
    {
        printf("%s", "Yes");
    } else
    {
        printf("%s", "No");
    }
}
```

First, don't calculate an string's length inside a loop. I extracted them into `len1` and `len2` variables.

Second, your loop was wrong! You shouldn't go up to `count`, you should go up to that string's length.

Third, you didn't return anything from `checkAnagram` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, makes sense going up to the length of the string rather than the alpha chars.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your count holds the count of non-space characters, but you keep the strings with the spaces.

For example, the string "hello world" has 11 characters, but if you run it through the loops your count will be 10 (you don't count the space). However, when you later go over the strings and count the appearance of each letter, you will go over the first 10 characters, therefore completely ignoring the last character - a 'd'.

To fix it, you need to go over *all* characters of the string, and only count the alphanumeric ones.

Comment: In which loop should I go over all characters? Are you saying I should change the first loop when getting 'count' or the other loops with 'letterCount'?